# Non SQL Post Deployment Scripts in DACPAC

Tags: sql-server, deployment, dacpac

Long time reader, first time asker!

I've been racking my brains about an issue i've been having, we are deploying DACPACs for our database code, in the new "DevOps" world it needs to pretty much one click and done. This should be possible to do within the MSI creation but i'm blue in the face from pushing the addition of that functionality so I'm keeping it in the DACPAC because I can control that side of things.

Does anyone know of a way to execute post/pre deployment scripts that aren't SQL. Ideally PowerShell but initially I just need to create folder structures and move some files around.

xp_cmdshell is out of the question for security reasons.

I thought about creating a SQL Agent job to run powershell automatically once post deployment then delete its self, but i'd rather not go through the route of lobbying that, it seems too messy.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: SQLCMD mode supports

> :!![Command]

e.g.

> :!!mkdir C:\Test

Unfortunately Visual studio doesn't support that level of SQLCMD so back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking at it slightly the wrong way round, instead of having the dacpac do other things what we normally do is have a powershell script that deploys the dacpac and then does x.

Typically there is a need to include in the deployment process a pre-pre-deployment script where we want to run some sql before the compare happens so the process is to have a powershell script that:

- Checks for the pre-pre deploy script and runs it
- Deploys the dacpac either by calling sqlpackage or using the DacServices .net library

In your case you would deploy your dacpac then do something else in your script.

Either way you would always want a script to do the deploy as you want to source control the parameters that you use (if passwords or environment specific things then they would be parameters etc)

Hope that makes sense, one thing you mention is that it should be one click and done - if this means a dba or someone clicking the dacpac to deploy then this isn't devops:)

Ed

Comment: Hey ed thanks for the reply, and yes a completely agree, I'm a PowerShell guy all the way so the ideal way would be deployment PS with adhoc extra scripts. Unfortunately I work in a very large organisation where some overpaid consultant has thrown some devops buzz words around and they've gone down a route that wouldn't allow that (they're wrapping them up in MSI's). I handed my notice in a couple of weeks ago because of stuff like that frustrating me, I'm just trying to come up with a solution to prove a point now more than anything :) Which i have, I'll post it now.

Comment: Nevermind my fix doesn't work in Visual Studio, I found the documentation for SQLCMD mode and you can run commands using :!!mkdir C:\Test however Visual studio doesn't support all SQLCMD functionality, handy thing to know in the future though!

Comment: If they are msi's can you not add an action to run after your done? MSI's have a MoveFileAction. Getting real ugly/hacky if you can code you can write a build executor, a .net dll that needs to be put in a specific location relative to sqlpackage that gets called when the deploy script is executed - you could then do what you like, before, during or after the execution of the deploy. To be honest, if your leaving in a couple of weeks I would document the different approaches and benefits of each and leave it for the next person to argue/cry about :) it sounds like they will change it anyway

Comment: You totally could, in fact the original developer they had was all up for custom actions and making it flexible. He got moved onto a different project unfortunately. Yeah a DLL could be a route to go, we actually allow CLR in our solutions so you could in theory have an environmental CLR behind a stored proc that is executed by anything really, which continuously checks folder structures based on a config table, long term that would be a good approach especially in the likely event the folder gets accidentally deleted.